# "Date is incompatible with int" error, but no INT parameters

Tags: sql-server-2012

I'm building an SP in SQL Server 2012. I'm getting the error message:

> Operand type clash: date is incompatible with int.

As you can see there are no INT parameters in my stored procedure.

Can anyone figure out what I'm missing?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE DailyTickets2 

    @rd0 DATE = NULL, 
    @rd1 DATE = NULL,
    @rd2 DATE = NULL

AS

    SET NOCOUNT ON;

BEGIN

    SET @rd0 = GETDATE()
    SET @rd1 = DATEADD(day,-1,@rd0)
    SET @rd2 = DATEADD(day,-2,@rd0)

-- Queued Tickets---
(
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN JOB_TICKET.JOB_TICKET_ID <= @rd1 AND JOB_TICKET.CLOSE_DATE IS NULL OR JOB_TICKET.CLOSE_DATE > @rd1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS rd1Queue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN JOB_TICKET.JOB_TICKET_ID <= @rd2 AND JOB_TICKET.CLOSE_DATE IS NULL OR JOB_TICKET.CLOSE_DATE > @rd2
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS rd2Queue
    FROM JOB_TICKET
    WHERE JOB_TICKET.MERGED_PARENT_TICKET_ID IS NULL 
        AND JOB_TICKET.DELETED = 0 
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN JOB_TICKET.REPORT_DATE >= @rd1 AND JOB_TICKET.REPORT_DATE < @rd0
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS rd1Opened,
    SUM(CASE WHEN JOB_TICKET.REPORT_DATE >= @rd2 AND JOB_TICKET.REPORT_DATE < @rd1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS rd2Opened
FROM JOB_TICKET
WHERE JOB_TICKET.MERGED_PARENT_TICKET_ID IS NULL 
        AND JOB_TICKET.DELETED = 0 
)
UNION ALL
(
SELECT
    SUM(CASE WHEN JOB_TICKET.CLOSE_DATE >= @rd1 AND JOB_TICKET.CLOSE_DATE < @rd0 
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS rd1Closed,
    SUM(CASE WHEN JOB_TICKET.CLOSE_DATE >= @rd2 AND JOB_TICKET.CLOSE_DATE < @rd1
        THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END) AS rd2Closed
FROM JOB_TICKET
WHERE JOB_TICKET.MERGED_PARENT_TICKET_ID IS NULL 
        AND JOB_TICKET.DELETED = 0 
)
END
GO
```

Comment: These statements are working fine. Error might be somewhere else. How do you call the procedure?

Comment: Since you left out the **signature** of the procedure (the `CREATE PROCEDURE` with the parameters) we cannot really know that there are no `INT` parameters......

Comment: Please edit your question with the full code of the stored procedure.

Comment: Edited with complete code

Comment: What is the data type of column JOB_TICKET.JOB_TICKET_ID in your query?

Comment: @Drishya1 it's an integer

Comment: Wow...That's it...I never even noticed that.  I have the wrong field named!  Forrest for the trees.  Thanks for asking the question that woke me up @Drishya1!

Comment: You are welcome!!